# How do I add Active Directory support to Windows PE?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I want to query Active Directory from Windows PE 2.0, which is not supported "out of the box." Microsoft seems to suggest that this is possible, but not with any tools they provide. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing [the ADSI package from deployvista.com](http://www.deployvista.com/Repository/WindowsPE20/tabid/73/EntryId/31/DMXModule/399/ctl/EntryDetails/mid/399/language/en-US/Default.aspx) solved the problem for me, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be instructions here, and the author claims to query AD from WinPE.
http://www.clientarchitect.com/blog1.php/2008/06/18/windows-pe-2-0-ad-scripting-requirements

Answer (score 1):

i recently needed to use a connection to AD from WinPE to retrieve some computer informations, i tested the above solution and other one with ADSI but not working for me in ADK 1709.

My final solution is using WMI on a DC with differed Credentials so can get all i need just by one line :)

(Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\directory\ldap' -Query "Select DS_info from DS_computer where DS_cn = $($AccountName)" -ComputerName $Domain -Credential $myADCred).$($Myattribute)

$AccountName : is the name of the computer i am searching in AD
$Domain : fqdn name that pointing to your DC ex:(xyz.youtdomain.com)
$MyADCred : is a credential object containing user and password with the necessary rights on AD
$myattribute : is the info i am searching from the computer in AD.

have a nice deployment :)

Yassine